# Bypass the open circuit

Tags: arduino, voltage, voltage-regulator, circuit-design, mains

I have a circuit in which bulb is attached, I want to let arduino know if bulb is functional or fused. Obviously when bulb will be fused it will become open circuit. I am using mains AC to power the bulb and I want to make feedback signal to send to an arduino

My bulb is running on 220 V controlled through relay.

I have connected the bulb in series with an AC - 5V DC converter, however, the bulb flickers when connected this way.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fi8WHD.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

How do I detect whether the bulb is conducting or blown?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: I'm not sure about the environment, however, maybe using a simple photo resistor close to the bulb might make an AC/DC converter obsolete.

Comment: Is the bulb connected to 220V?

Comment: You haven't supplied enough information.  **1)**  Do you want to know if the bulb is open when it is supposed to be **OFF** or when it is supposed to be **ON**  or both?  Each condition (supposed to be OFF or ON) requires different techniques.  **2)** Is the bulb resistive (incandescent) or electronic (LED or CFL).  **3)**  What voltage and current is the bulb?

Comment: Yes bulb is connected to 220V. I have connected a power supply of 220 to 5V dc to get output to arduino, but bulb starts flickering as I apply this circuit.

Comment: If the bulb is flickering, stop whatever you're doing with that circuit...

Comment: Am I the only one confused about the word "**fused**"?  To me, it means either: 1) The component is in series with a fuse, or 2) The component has melted *closed* (is shorted). But OP is using it to mean *open*...

Comment: You can use a hall sensor or a current transformer. But these solutions are not cheap...Be careful. 220V are dangerous to humans!

Comment: @bort review I have updated my question with more details

Comment: @bort fused means bulb is dis functional now, in more precise words, bulb has blown up.

Comment: @dwayneReid, Is now information complete. I have updated my question

Comment: In short words I just want to bypass bulb when it is dis-functional

Comment: Because the bulb is in series, it is only getting 220 minus what the converter is dropping.  Meanwhile the converter is only getting 220 minus what the bulb would drop.  This is unlikely to ever work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The switching power will only draw as much current as it needs to power the 5V side of the circuit. Since you're drawing almost no current, the buck converter will only turn on every so often to keep the output voltage at 5V.

Instead, you might want to try wrapping a single turn of wire around one of the wires going to the bulb, and connecting it to a rectifier and zener diode. Something like this.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fCwB0I.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

(Note, may work without all of the components shown)

Alternatively, you could use a photoresistor/photodiode to sense whether the light is on. Just make sure if your bulb is incandescent that you don't melt your wires.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't really ask a question so I'm asking why the bulb is flickering or at least my guess why.

You have the bulb in series with the AC/DC converter. The converter might only lets power flow part of the time, switching on and off making the bulb flicker in the same frequency.